# Carbon date is empty when I run Insert statement

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

I'm starin to use Carbon to manage Dates in PHP with MySQL, but I'm having problems with a simple Insert statement. To run SQL statements I'm using Medoo, this is my code to insert:

```
public function register($code, $fullname, $address, $phones, $email, $now){

    $registration = $this->_app['medoo']->insert("customers",[
        'cus_code' => $code,
        'cus_fullname' => $fullname,
        'cus_address' => $address,
        'cus_phone_s' => $phones,
        'cus_email' => $email,
        'created_at' => $now
    ]);


    return $registration;

}
```

And this is where I pass the value:

```
$code = $request->get('code');
$name = $request->get('name');
$phones = $request->get('phone_s');
$address = $request->get('address');
$email = $request->get('email');
$now = Carbon::now('America/Monterrey');

$customer_registration = $app['customer.model']->register($code, $name, $address, $phones, $email, $now);`

if($customer_registration){
     $request_status = true;
 }else {
     $request_errors[] = "Ocurrio un error al registrar el cliente";
 }
```

The statement returns an error and this is the output if I debug it:

```
INSERT INTO "customers" 
("cus_code", "cus_fullname", "cus_address", "cus_phone_s", "cus_email", "created_at") 
 VALUES 
('n20', 'notaria 20', 'lerdo 202', '1234567890', 'mail@mail.com')
```

As you can see, the date is missing and It doesn't make any sense because if I echo it inside my function...

```
public function register($code, $fullname, $address, $phones, $email, $now){
   echo '<p>this is the variable now: '.$now.'</p>';
    $this->_app['medoo']->debug()->insert("customers",[
        'cus_code' => $code,
        'cus_fullname' => $fullname,
        'cus_address' => $address,
        'cus_phone_s' => $phones,
        'cus_email' => $email,
        'created_at' => $now
    ]);

    die();

    return $registration;

}
```

outputs...

```
  this is the variable now: 2017-05-14 00:52:00

  INSERT INTO "customers" 
  ("cus_code", "cus_fullname", "cus_address", "cus_phone_s", "cus_email", "created_at") 
  VALUES 
  ('n20', 'notaria20', 'lerdo 202', '1234567890', 'mail@mail.com')
```

I changed **$now** for Date('Y-m-d H:m:s') and It works, but for my app I need to use Carbon.

I hope I was clear with this, I'm not so good with english, please help!

Comment: Did you imported the carbon class in both your controller and model?

Comment: Yes I did it 'use Carbon\Carbon;'

Comment: Just pass Carbon::now() and check if it gives you the date

Comment: I already make the test, but It still now working, It only works with date('Y-m-d H:m:s') not with Carbon

Comment: how come the variable printed as `2017-05-14 00:52:00` but not inserting `created_at`? would you try to direct query of `insert into ..values(variables...$now)` and see the result

Comment: ok, the sentence generated was: INSERT INTO `customers` (`cus_code`, `cus_fullname`, `cus_address`, `cus_phone_s`, `cus_email`, `created_at`) VALUES ('kokokoko', 'kokokokok', 'okokoko', 'okokok', 'kokokok@j.com', '2017-05-14 09:05:07');

Comment: I was able to Insert but the date was generated by date('Y-m-d H:m:s') not Carbon

Comment: You may have to convert the Carbon::now as string value.

Comment: I solved it @Angolao by doing this: Carbon::now('America/Monterrey')->format('Y-m-d H:m:s');, Thank you bro!

Answer (score 0):

The answer of this question is in comments and which is not the way to post in SO so I am posting the answer here to close the question.

Here he needs to pass timestamp in `SQL` format as laravel's `insert()` doesn't affect `created_at` and `updated_at` values and needs manual efforts to add `created_at` values, so the correct way to pass it into `insert()` method manually should be:

```
Carbon::now('America/Monterrey')->format('Y-m-d H:m:s');
```

Thus the code should look like this

```
$now =Carbon::now('America/Monterrey')->format('Y-m-d H:m:s');
$this->_app['medoo']->debug()->insert("customers",[
        'cus_code' => $code,
        'cus_fullname' => $fullname,
        'cus_address' => $address,
        'cus_phone_s' => $phones,
        'cus_email' => $email,
        'created_at' => $now
    ]);
```